# excuting perl from the web?

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi

I have a Perl script, `Main.pl`, that reads in a text and outputs an XML document. When I SSH into my Unix server and run the script from the command line, it outputs the right XML; but when I visit `http://localhost/Main2.pl` in my browser, it just shows the Perl code, and when I try to POST to it in a jQuery-enabled web-page (using `$.post("http://localhost/Main2.pl")`), it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

You can see the Perl script at http://moxie.cs.oswego.edu/~cmunger2/coursework/Poetry_project/Main2.pl; the page that's trying to use it is http://moxie.cs.oswego.edu/~cmunger2/coursework/Poetry_project/index.html.

Comment: have you tried putting your perl file in a folder called "cgi-bin" ?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not constructive.  Please specify what happens and include enough of the script to aid in diagnosis.

Comment: Presumably you haven't configured your web-server to run Perl-scripts accessed in this way. (And perhaps your web-server doesn't even offer such a feature.) If you want help with this, you'll really need to indicate what web-server you're using. (And you can remove all the JavaScript/jQuery stuff from your question; your statement "If I actually go to the script in the url it just shows the perl code" guarantees that all of that is irrelevant.)

Comment: why do I get down vote for my questions?  and no I didn't know you had to.  in the code do I call it from the same place?

Comment: @ruakh It's a university server.  I don't have sudo.

Comment: @KirsKringle: I never mentioned `sudo`.

Comment: By the way, your page's `<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` does not work, because `jquery.js` is (apparently) *not* in the same directory as your `index.html`.

Comment: @ruakh it's in there, but has the version numbers after, I need to fix that.  By sudo I meant I don't have access to the server in anymore way then they allow me to.  It is likely they don't allow this sort of activity on their server. Sorry if I seem dumb to you, just starting out and I'm doing this as a above and beyond project for a creative writing course.

Comment: @KirsKringle: You don't seem dumb, but as far as this question is concerned, I don't think it really matters whether you have access to change the server configuration. If the conclusion ends up being "the only way this will work is if the server is changed in such-and-such way", then you'll need to talk to your university; but there are many other possible conclusions. To find them, you'll need to tell us *what* web-server you're using, not *whose*.

Comment: (Actually, more generally, you should probably talk to your university. If they've enabled CGI, then they can probably give you precise instructions for how to use it, and if they haven't, then they can tell you whether or not they're willing to do so.)

Comment: @ruakh the server is running Solaris 9/10, Server is Apache/2.4.2(Unix)  Is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl scripts are executed on the server, while JavaScript is executed on the user's machine.  Because of this, you need to configure your web server to allow scripts to be executed, as well as what paths they can be executed in.  This is due to the fact that when run from the web, you are allowing essentially anyone to run code on your server, which can be a big security problem.  You can execute your script fine when you SSH, because you have logged in as a privileged user.  Web privileges are locked down for the security reasons I mentioned.

Generally, most web servers allow Perl scripts to be executed from a default `/cgi-bin` directory, and they are usually named with a `.cgi` extension.  Sometimes a server will only allow `.cgi` scripts to be executed, although they can be exactly the same as a `.pl` script.

I would look into how to configure executables from your web server, or if you are using a web host (or looks like you are using a university server), look into how they configure executable access.  There is probably already a default executable area, such as `/cgi-bin`.

It's entirely possible that your particular university server does not allow executable access, but you won't know until you do some research/asking around.  The presence/absence of a `/cgi-bin` directory may be a telltale sign.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.  I'm sure that is likely the problem as they probably don't want everyone running code on their servers.

Answer (score 2):

The server is not configured to run CGI scripts from that location.

In addition, even if it were, you'd be getting `500` errors as your Perl script is not a proper CGI script. At the very least, you'll need to output a header specifying the content type you are returning and the encoding which matches the encoding of the XML document.